# Race conditions on parallel Paxos instances running

Tags: distributed, race-condition, paxos

I'm confused about using Paxos algorithm.
Seems that Paxos can be used to such scenario: multiple server (a cluster, I assume each server has all 3 roles, proposer, acceptor, leaner) need to keep the same command sequences to achieve consistence and backup. I assume there are some clients sending commands to this server (clients may send in parallel). Each time the command is dispatched to multiple server by one Paxos instance.

1. Different clients can send different commands to different proposers, Right?

If so, one command from some client will raise a Paxos instance. So,

2. Multiple Paxos instance may run at the same time?

If so, client-A sends "A += 1" command to proposer-A, and client-B sends "B += 2" command to proposer-B at nearly the same time, I suppose to see each server has received 2 commands, "A += 1" and "B += 2".

However,

3. Given 5 servers, say S1-S5, S1 send command "A += 1" and S5 send command "B += 1", S2 promise S1 however S3, S4 promise S5, so finally S3,S4,S5 got "B += 1" but S1,S2 got nothing because the number of promise is not majority. Seems like the Paxos does not help at all. We don't get the expected "A += 1" and "B += 2" at all 5 servers?
4. So I guess in practical application of Paxos, no parallel Paxos instances are allowed? If so, how to avoid parallel Paxos instances, seems that we still need a centralized server to flag whether there is a Paxos running or not if we allowed multiple clients and multiple proposers.
5. Also, I have questions about the proposer number. I search the internet and some claims the following
   is a solution:
   5 servers, given corresponding index k(0-4), each server uses number 5*i + k for this server's "i"th proposal.

For me, this seems not meet the requirements at all, because server-1's first proposal number is always 1 and server-4's first proposal number is always 4, but server-4 may raise the proposal earlier than server-1, however it's proposal number is bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I guess in practical application of Paxos, no parallel Paxos
>   instances are allowed? If so, how to avoid parallel Paxos instances,
>   seems that we still need a centralized server to flag whether there is
>   a Paxos running or not if we allowed multiple clients and multiple
>   proposers.

You don't need a centralised service only need nodes to redirect clients to the current leader. If they don't know who the leader is they should throw an error and the client should select another node from DNS/config until they find or are told the current leader. Clients only need a reasonably up to date list of which nodes are in the cluster so that they can contact a majority of current nodes then they will find the leader when it becomes stable.

If nodes get separated during a network partition you may get lucky and its a clean and stable partition which only leads to one majority and it will get a new stable leader. If you get an unstable partition or some dropped directional packets such that two or nodes start to be "duelling leaders" then you can use randomised timeouts and adaptive back-off to minimise two nodes attempting to get elected at the same time leading to failed rounds and wasted messages. Clients will get wasted redirects, errors or timeouts and will be scanning for the leader during a duel until it is resolved to a stable leader.

Effectively paxos goes for CP out of CAP so it can loose the A (availability) due to duelling leaders or no majority being able to communicate. Perhaps if this really was high risk in practice people would be writing about having nodes blacklist any node which repeatedly tries to lead but which never gets around to committing due to persistent unstable network partition issues. Pragmatically one can imagine that folks monitoring the system will get alerts and kill such a node and fix the network before trying to add complex "works unattended no matter what" features into their protocol.

With respect to the number for proposals a simple scheme is a 64bit long with a 32bit counter packed into the highest bits and the 32bit IP address of the node packed into the lowest bits. That makes all numbers unique and interleaved and only assumes you don't run multiple nodes on the same machine.

If you take a look at Multi-Paxos on Wikipedia  it's about optimising the flow for a stable leader. Failovers should be really rare so once you get a leader it can gallop with accept messages only and skip proposals. When you are galloping if you are bit packing the leader identity into the event numbers a node can see that subsequent accepts are from the same leader and are sequential for that leader. The galloping with a stable leader is a good optimisation and creating a new leader with proposals is an expensive thing requiring proposal messages and the risk of duelling leaders so should be avoid unless it is cluster startup or failover.

Comment: so you mean in practical only the leader proposer is responsible for proposing clients's requests, thus avoiding multiple paxos instances running at the same time?

Comment: I'm still confused about the proposal number. Your proposal number solution seems similar to the one I listed, different proposer using different number space and this just guarantee the latter number is bigger in the same node. However, this is not enough to guarantee the later proposal has the bigger number on different node as I explained on the question.

Comment: Any node can promote to leader by making a successful proposal and that's required to make a leader; but can be expensive. If all nodes timeout on a dead leader at 10ms then all make proposals at the same time it will be a big fight and only one node can win.  Make each node timeout at rand()*60s then you likely won't get a leadership fight; but will have to wait on average may seconds random delay before a new candidate leader proposes.

Comment: Here is the code for the bit packing of the proposal https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5805c5708c41de3f0311 if you run that you can can see it creates interleaving numbers. With the number you can extract the counter, increment it, then create a new proposal using the current server number. A less efficient way to to it is "counter * 100 + serverId" assuming serverId runs from 0 to 99. Or you can use only on byte of for bit packing.

Comment: @user3745804 this short animated slide show shoes leader timeouts and fingering leaders. It's taken from the raft paper which uses something very much like basic Paxos for leader proposal and election but the ideas on timeout and multiple clashing proposals are the same as basic Paxos so it shows the point well that it's expensive so you want randomised timeouts. http://thesecretlivesofdata.com/raft/

Answer (score 0):

> however it's proposal number is bigger.

That's exactly the point of partitioning the proposal space. The rule is, that only the most recent proposal, the one with the highest number seen, shall be accepted. Thus, if three proposals were sent out, only the one proposal with the largest number will ever get an accepted majority.

If you do not do that, chances are that multiple parties continue to spit out proposals with simply incremented numbers (`nextNumber = ++highestNumberSeen`) like crazy and never come to a consensus.

Comment: but the largest number is not exactly the last one proposed and this does not meet the requirement of paxos.

Comment: "*but the largest number is not exactly the last one proposed *" - correct. I never said that.

Comment: you mean this is not required? what's your opinion on my other confusions, such as running multiple paxos intances at the same time? How does real world using paxos algorithm?

Comment: The data model behind is that of a state machine. Paxos is about getting consensus about a particular transition being the next one (or not) to be applied to that state machine. If and only if the algorithm reaches consensus, all parties involved do the same transition. Assumed all parties know the identical previous state `S[N]`, the following State `S[N+1]`  after aplying transition T will be as well: `S[N+1] = S[N] + T`. Given all parties learn at startup about what Lamport calls the "current state of the law" and continue from that point onwards, everything will be just fine.